# Vertex painting how to

Tags: node-editor, vertex-colors, shader-nodes, vertex-paint

First pic below shows the horns and the node setup.  The horns were masked and done as a separate vertex color index.  Not sure if this was necessary and might well be complicating things.
[image: pic1]

Second pic shows the face and a blended node setup.
[image: pic2]

How can I combine both the horns and the face into one?

Comment: Colour add node?

Comment: You have a "Vertex Color" node you can use instead of "Attribute"

Comment: Vertex color nodes come in as Attribute nodes...